# Algebra 2 & Matrix

Tags: matrices

what does a small number on the base of a letter mean? I do not understand it and I am working on a problem in my Algebra 2 class that has that in it.

Comment: It depends.  Can you write out (or take a picture of) where you see the symbol in context?

Comment: It's probably an index number ($x_1$, $x_2$,...), a way of denoting variables or parameters. But a picture will help us to clarify your doubt.

Comment: Do you mean like this: $x_2$? Then I'd say the second entry of vector $x$, judging by your title. But as Bye_World says, it can have multiple meanings.

Comment: Or if you have something like $a_{34}$ then it usually means the entry in the third row and fourth column of the matrix $A$.